# SQL aggregate function

Tags: sql, ms-access-2007, aggregate-functions

I want to run a query in which I have to count no of itemsModel in the database which is in MS Access 2007 and also to multiply that count with the rate with i have kept in the different table.

```
SELECT 
    AllocateAsset.Item, AllocateAsset.ItemModel, 
    COUNT(AllocateAsset.ItemModel) AS CountOfItem,    
    (COUNT(AllocateAsset.ItemModel) * rateList.Rate) AS Amount
```

I'm getting an error that:

> it is not right expression ...

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please do not mark questions as urgent here or on any other forum on the web - everyone who answers is a volunteer, and all questions are equally important. I have downvoted to remind you, with regret.

Comment: thank you for tip ... i will keep that in mind .

Answer (score 0):

you need to add a group by statement:

```
group by AllocateAssettItem, AllocateAsset.ItemModel
```

Comment: i have alsready added group by statement and its is working fine but  i m not getting how to multiply Count(Allocate.ItemModel) As CuntOfItem with rate ... please help me in this .... when i add (COUNT(AllocateAsset.ItemModel) * rateList.Rate) AS Amount this expression it gives me an error